# Screen turned off on resume, HDMI issue

Tags: 14.04, display, suspend

I have an HP Pavilion G4
AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4
14.04 Trusty

For some time now, whenever I suspend notebook either by shutting lid or manual suspension screen is off. Recently by chance I have tried to resume whyle hooked to external HDMI TV and realised that HDMI is set to default output on suspension. both video and audio output go to HDMI as usual. But trying to get back to notebook screen gets me nowhere, it remains turned off untill rebooted.

I have also noticed that despite having HDMI unhooked, HDMI audio output device is still detected.

Can anyone shed some light to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Go into your Power Settings
- Look for `When lid is closed`, change that to `Do Nothing`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not solve my problem as i need to carry this around and cant just keep it on all day long. I WANT to suspend my machine as usual, just need to make sure it detects HDMI is not pluged in so that it resumes to internal display